# Calculating text length of node in memory with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to calculate the length of an svg `<text>` in memory (not in actual DOM). Is this possible? If not what are the possible solutions?

I have the snippet below but it says

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: text.node(...).getComputedTextLength is not a function",

Here's the snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var text1 = svg.append("text")
 .attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y", 30)
 .text("Hello world!");

console.log("the text in DOCUMENT has " + text1.node().getComputedTextLength() + " px")

var div = document.createElement('div');
var svg = d3.select(div).append('svg');
text2 = svg.append("text")
 .attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y", 30)
 .text("Hello world!");
console.log("the text in MEMORY has " + text2.node().getComputedTextLength() + " px")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like you created an image in the second example. You need an `append('svg')` to create one in the div.
However, I still don't think that will do it because text widths aren't calculated until the image is rendered. (At least when I tried it, the length printed was 0.)

Comment: You are right. I've fixed my example now. Looks like your explanation is right. What could be the solution then because I don't want to have an *FOUC* when I append the `svg` on the document.

Comment: All you need to do is have an "off-screen" SVG that you add the text to for measuring.  Something like `<svg id="offscreen" width="0" height="0"></svg>` should do it.